# Block requests to specific domain CefSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have cefsharp ChromiumWebBrowser. For example i'm opening discord.com website and in the background site itself making requests to discordapp.com. How can i block requests to discordapp.com domain?

I tried using custom IRequestHandler.OnBeforeBrowse, but it trigers only when opening site, not when site making requests.

In chrome i found this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-request-blocker/eckpjmeijpoipmldfbckahppeonkoeko and it's working fine, but idk how to do same in cefsharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
public class CustomRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.RequestHandler
{
    protected override IResourceRequestHandler GetResourceRequestHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isNavigation, bool isDownload, string requestInitiator, ref bool disableDefaultHandling)
    {

        if (request.Url.Contains("discordapp"))
        {
            return new CustomResourceRequestHandler();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class CustomResourceRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.ResourceRequestHandler
{
    protected override CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
    {

        request.Url = "";
        request.Dispose();

        return CefReturnValue.Cancel;
    }
}
```

```
browser.RequestHandler = new CustomRequestHandler();
```